# Remove keypad along with ModalBottomSheetLayout in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

After clicking outside BottomSheet, BottomSheet is hidden but the keypad remains persistent.
I want to remove the keypad as soon as BottomSheet is hidden in ModalBottomSheetLayout

[After clicking the text in compose keypad pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajcoj.png)
[After clicking outside bottom sheet, bottom sheet disappears but keypad persists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GaRl.png)

```
val state = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetContent = {
        Column {
            var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = text,
                label = { Text("Text") },
                onValueChange = { text = it }
            )
            var text1 by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = text1,
                label = { Text("Text1") },
                onValueChange = { text1 = it }
            )
            OutlinedButton(
                onClick = { click() },
            ) { Text(text = "SUBMIT") }
        }
    },
    sheetState = state,
    content = {
        Greeting(state = state, scope = scope)
    }
)
```

Comment: Did you fix your problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to hide the keyboard when `ModalBottomSheet` is hidden:

```
val keyboard = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
    confirmStateChange = {
    if (it == ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden) {
       keyboard?.hide()
    }
    true
})
ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetBackgroundColor = TinderTheme.colors.transparent,
    sheetState = sheetState,
...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add keyboard options and actions for the text fields. The keyboard options setup what type of keyboard and action you have on the keyboard. The onAction you pass the lambda to hide the bottom sheet and clear the focus:

```
val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    skipHalfExpanded = true,
    initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden
)
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

OutlinedTextField(
    value = text,
    label = { Text("Text") },
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
        imeAction = ImeAction.Done
    ),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
        onDone = {
            coroutineScope.launch {
                focusRequester.freeFocus()
                sheetState.hide()
            }
        }
    )
)
```